# How to test random.choice in Python?

Tags: python, testing, random

How would you test a function which could lead to a random choice?

For instance:

```
from random import shuffle

def getMaxIndices(lst):
    '''
    :lst: list of int

    Return indices of max value. If max value appears more than once,
    we chose one of its indices randomly.
    '''
    index_lst = [(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(lst)]
    shuffle(index_lst)
    index_lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    max_index = index_lst.pop()[0]
    return max_index
```

How would you test it?

Comment: What do you want to test? That the random generator is truly random, or that your logic behaves correctly for all the possible random input? Would you really need the first? And if it's the latter: Just decouple your handling of the input values from the random number generation, just inject the a number to the handler and unit test that handler.

Comment: I totally agree with your first point, I should not have writen this function, just the docstring. I am not sure to understand your second point (actually, i'm sure I don't), could you please be more explicit ?

Comment: My second point is about not caring of the randomness of the source value. Let's assume you want to randomly greet a customer either by "Good day!" and "What's up!". Then all you need is a function that accepts an integer, e.g. `0` for "Good day"  and `1` for `"What's up". This function need not know that the input is random, it just needs to accept a certain range of inputs for which to output an appropriate result. And that you can unit test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are not testing the shuffling itself, you should patch `shuffle` to return an output set by you in order to have a deterministic test.

In this case it could be something along the lines of:

```
@patch('random.shuffle', lambda x: x)
def test_get_max_Indices():
    max_index = getMaxIndices([4,5,6,7,8])
    assert max_index == 4
```

From the test, you can realise that the return value will simply be dependent on the length of the input list.

You can read more about patch in the docs: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test it, you can write something like:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,5]
assert getMaxIndices(lst) in (4,5)
```

testing that the result is either 4 or 5.

If you want to test that it can be both and is random, run it 1000 times and test that you get 4 and 5 about the same amount of times:

```
result = 0
for i in range(1000):
    result += getMaxIndices(lst)
assert 4.3 <= result/1000 <= 4.7
```

Comment: Someone has seen the same error and has edited the question. The problem with that test is that it would work if my function returns 4 every times.

Comment: Edited to test the randomness

Comment: Randomness is so weird that for one test run to always return `4` would be completely valid. So I don't think that it should mark the test as failing if it happens. (I do remember writing a coin flip program, just to see how often I had to restart in order to get 10, 100 or 1000 heads in a row. 10 heads is rather easy, 1000 ranges in the millions retries, yet it does happen.) Or just watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwvIGNXY21Y

Comment: Instead, rather work with the same random seed to always generate the same random numbers in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this many years later, but I would have some tests for edges cases like an empty list

```
import pytest
def test_get_max_empty_list():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        getMaxIndices([])
```

I would also test I got the largest, regardless of what the shuffle does:

```
def test_get_max_is_largest_for_two_identical_items():
    L = [2,2]
    max_index = getMaxIndices(L)
    assert L[max_index] == max(L)

def test_get_max_is_largest():
    L = [2,3,4,5,6]
    max_index = getMaxIndices(L)
    assert L[max_index] == max(L)
```

Mocking out the shuffle is fine, and does let you test specifics too, but doesn't cover the empty edge case.